# Как загрузить файл на сервер ВКонтакте через API?

Tags: node.js, vkontakte-api

Нужно загрузить локальный файл во ВКонтакте через API, но как это сделать? По поисковому запросу в Google все ответы датируются 2014 годом. Использую модуль `request`.

Comment: Ну с 2014 года вроде бы ничего принципиально не изменилось же?

Comment: Главное не забывать указывать версию API, и проблем не будет :)

Comment: @andreymal там в ответах какой-то громоздкий код с формами. На деле всё оказалось значительно проще.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто. Нужно отправить POST-запрос по адресу, выданному методом `photos.getWallUploadServer` и в параметре `formData` передать изображение под ключом `photos`.

```
request.post({
    url: urlToUpload,
    formData: {
        photo: fs.createReadStream(imgAddr)
    }
}, function(err, response, body) {});
```